# How do i make it understand that aos is equal to amount so that the user can input a number of arrays in c?

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int amount();
float average(int array[]);

int main(void)

//me begging to get the code to understand that aos is equal to amount();
int aos = amount();
{
    //ask for scores and print them
    int scores[aos];
    for (int i=0;i<aos;i++)
    {
        scores[i] = get_int("score: ");
    }
    printf("average: %f\n", average(scores));
}

//get amount of scores
int amount()

{
    int amt;
    do
    {
        amt = get_int("how many scores: ");
    }
    while (amt < 0);
    return amt;
}

//get amount of arrays and average
float average(int array[])

{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<aos; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum / (float) aos;
}
```

specifically
`int aos = amount();`
gives me headaches as whereever i put it it usually ends up giving me the message "initializer element is not a compile-time constant" which i dont know how to fix

i tried to put the line into various places and tried to structure it in a way that does not anger the compiler. at this point i am unsure wether it might aswell just be a form error that i missed. anyhow im all new to coding and started learning about arras abour 3 hours ago so im all outta options

Comment: `int aos = amount();` needs to be inside the braces of the `main` function. Move it down 2 lines. `for (int i = 0; i<aos; i++)` isn't going to wkr either unless you pass the `aos` variable to the `average` function.

Comment: There's a very strange use of `{ ... }` here to, I can only assume, force scoping of particular variables in one case, but as you have a habit of adding a blank line after function definitions, those too read like the same thing. That's not a standardized coding style and it's quite distracting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the statement `int aos = amount();` is not correct according to C syntax. It is only by scrolling further into your code that it becomes apparent you want `aos` to be available to the function `average`.

Here is your code revised and commented:

```
#include <stdio.h> // better to list most generic ahead of others
#include <cs50.h>

// Defining functions ahead of their use obviates the need for function prototypes.
// This eliminates an extra point of maintenance
float average( int array[], int aos ) // pass all the required values as arguments
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<aos; i++)
    {
        sum += array[i];
    }
    return sum / (float) aos; // or sum could be float the whole time
}

int amount( void ) // be specific about arguments
{
    int amt;
    do
    {
        amt = get_int("how many scores: ");
    }
    while (amt < 1); // Changed from 0 to 1. Dividing by zero is undefined!

    return amt;
}

// Notice the use of additional whitespace below to aid legibility.
int main(void)
{
    int nScores = amount(); // changed variable name here

    int scores[ nScores ];
    for ( int i = 0; i < nScores; i++ )
    {
        scores[ i ] = get_int("score: ");
    }
    printf( "average: %f\n", average( scores, nScores ) );

    return 0; // optional, but I prefer this be present.
}
```

This formatting represents one of several *conventional* styles used. Personal variations (such as an extra blank line ahead of a function body) are to be discouraged, especially if others will be reading your code.

One could go on to write about using `size_t` variables, or `const` declarations of arguments, but this is enough for now.

Answer (score -1):

```
int main(void)

    // me begging to get the code to understand that aos is
    // equal to amount();
    int aos = amount();
{
```

This `{` should be at the start of `main` as

```
int main(void)
{
    // me begging to get the code to understand that aos is
    // equal to amount();
    int aos = amount();
    // ask for scores and print them
    int scores[aos];
    for (int i = 0; i < aos; i++)
    {
        scores[i] = get_int("score: ");
    }
    printf("average: %f\n", average(scores));
}
```

*"initializer element is not a compile-time constant"*

refers to this line

```
    int scores[aos];
```

And the compiler is telling you that `aos`, the value you used to initialize the size of the `scores` array, is not a compile time constant. **No surprise here. It is not**: it is a value returned by a function at run-time. You must provide a value when you write the program, or allocate the array as soon as you know the value, when the program is running.
There is a thing called VLA but you should not count on its existence or implementation in your compiler.

You can **[1]** estimated a max value for `scores` or **[2]** allocate the array at runtime.

#### [1] just use a max size and adjust `aos`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int   amount();
float average(int array[], int size);

int main(void)
{
    // me begging to get the code to understand that aos is
    // equal to amount();
    int aos = amount();
    // now the code understanding that you can have at most
    // 30 scores...
    if (aos > 30) aos = 30;
    // sure, you could write
    // aos = (aos > 30) ? 30 : aos;
    int scores[30];
    for (int i = 0; i < aos; i++)
        scores[i] = get_int("score: ");
    // now you tell average the # of scores
    printf("average: %f\n", average(scores,aos));
}

// get amount of scores
int amount()

{
    int amt;
    do {
        amt = get_int("how many scores: ");
    } while (amt < 0);
    return amt;
}

// get amount of arrays and average
float average(int array[], int aos)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < aos; i++) { sum += array[i]; }
    return sum / (float)aos;
}
```

#### [2] create `scores[]` only when `aos` is known

```
int main(void)
{
    int aos = amount();
    // now that you know the size, tell it
    // to the compiler
    int* scores = malloc(aos * sizeof(aos));
    // aos can even be negative as you used `int`
    // so malloc can fail
    if (scores == NULL) return -1; // as an error
    for (int i = 0; i < aos; i++)
        scores[i] = i;
    //scores[i] = get_int("score: ");
    // now you tell average the # of scores
    printf("average: %f\n", average(scores, aos));
    // now socres[] has no use: you must free the memory
    free(scores);
    // this can save you from using an adress of a thing
    // that does not exist anymore
    scores = NULL; // free memory, invalidate pointer
    return 0;
}
```

In short

```
    int aos = amount();
    int* scores = malloc(aos * sizeof(aos));
```

This way as soon as `aos` is known you call `malloc` and get a pointer to an area with the required size.

Then you change `average` to

```
    float average(int* array, int size);
```

passing the address of the array.

After using `scores` you call `free` to , well, free the allocated memory. To set the pointer to `NULL` is a good habit. Not all your programs will have 20 lines and the memory pointed by `scores` is no longer valid after you call `free`, so it can save you from a few bugs...

Comment: `int* scores = malloc(aos * sizeof(aos));` only works because `aos` is an `int`... Taking the size of an unrelated variable is a bug waiting to happen. AND, you missed the possibility of _division by zero_... (Or, perhaps `malloc()` will crash when asked to allocate 0 bytes...) `aos` cannot be negative...

Comment: @Fe2O3 thanks for pointing this, but note that this is not a bug. `malloc` should take any expression and convert it to `size_t`, a non-negative thing. `malloc()` for a negative size just returns `NULL` and the program returns at the following line.

Comment: @Fe2O3 `malloc(0)` will not crash. It can return `NULL` or a funny pointer to nothing, as stated in 7.22.23 in the standard. BTOH ,the chance of division by zero is unrelated to the question. It is just the original program